# Setting several tabular tables behind each other

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

Surprisingly the arranged tables(as a whole ) differ in left alignment. They should be aligned in one manner like the first one.
MWE:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    % usually 6pt
    % \setlength{\tabcolsep}{50pt} %da auch der erste Spalteninhalt nach re. gesetzt wird, sinnlos
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25} % default: 1
    
    \section*{Telefonlisten Ga xxx Ke e rs}
    \begin{tabular}{l@{\hskip 50pt}l@{ }l@{\hskip 35pt}r@{ - }l} 
    %\begin{tabular}{ll@{ }lr@{ - }l} 
    % Headline
    \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textbf{Betrieb sssssss}}  Betriebszeiten (08:00)07:00 - 16:30\\ \hline
    % Spaltenbezeichnung
    Ansprech & {Telefon} & & Pause von&bis \\ \hline
    % Rows
    B\"uro & 12345 & 111 62 & 12:30 & 13:00  \\ 
    aaaaa & 01573 & 111 34 22 &   & \\  
    aaaaa & 0160 & 111 54 41 41 &   & \\  
    aaaaa & 0173 & 111 25 22 & 09:00 & 09:30  \\  
    aaaaa & 01516 & 111 12 30 & 12:30 & 13:00  \\  
    aaaaaaa & 01520 & 111 37 89 & 15:00 & 15:10  \\  
    \end{tabular}
    
    \bigskip
    
    \begin{tabular}{l@{\hskip 50pt}l@{ }l@{\hskip 35pt}r@{ - }l} 
    %\begin{tabular}{ll@{ }lr@{ - }l} 
    % Headline
    \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textbf{Betrieb viunhz \& jhgttaa}}  Betriebszeiten (08:00)07:00 - 16:30\\ \hline
    % Spaltenbezeichnung
    Ansprech & {Telefon} & & Pause von&bis \\ \hline
    % Rows
    bbbbbbb & 11111 & 222 22 22 & 09:00 & 09:20  \\ 
    bbbbbbbb & 21212 & 222 55 22 & 12:00  & 12:30 \\  
    bbbbbbbbbbb & 11111 & 111 33 02 & 15:00  & 15:30\\  
    \end{tabular}
    
    \bigskip
    \end{document}
```

Output:
[image: No vertical alignment]

Comment: Depending on the desired output, you could also use a single `tabular` environment for both tables. With this approach, all columns in both tables would be aligned equally. If you have more than just the two tables and need page breaks, you could use a single `longtable` instead.

Comment: @leandris Good idea, but none of these pseudo tables in longtable should be broken without its lineheader "Betrieb". The idea is, that the longtable "respect" the internal headlines viz. "Betrieb...".  If you think that is possible an example would be needed.

Comment: You can prevent pagebreaks in a longtable by using `\\*` as opposed to `\\ `. Thus, this requirement could also be met using `longtable`.

Comment: @leandris the breaking of longtable is not predictable, so not fixed.  But the breaks for the pseudo table are at row with content "Betrieb".  So, when longtable breaks it should break in that manner that the row "Betrieb" appears as the first row on new page. longtable should recognize the row "Betrieb", go back to it and breaks at this point. I don't think that it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edit

Following Mico's suggestion I'd like to add that the first paragraph *does not get indented*. This is why only the second and consecutive tables are shifted by the amount assigned to `\parindent`.

KOMA-Script sets `\parindent` to `1em` by default, if I'm not mistaken. Since a new table – in a way – constitutes a new paragraph it gets indented by 1em.

Just place a `\noindent` in front of the second (or third, fourth etc.) table:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    
\begin{document}
    
% usually 6pt
% \setlength{\tabcolsep}{50pt} %da auch der erste Spalteninhalt nach re. gesetzt wird, sinnlos
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25} % default: 1
    
\section*{Telefonlisten Ga xxx Ke e rs}
\begin{tabular}{l@{\hskip 50pt}l@{ }l@{\hskip 35pt}r@{ - }l} 
%\begin{tabular}{ll@{ }lr@{ - }l} 
% Headline
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textbf{Betrieb sssssss}}  Betriebszeiten (08:00)07:00 - 16:30\\ \hline
% Spaltenbezeichnung
Ansprech & {Telefon} & & Pause von&bis \\ \hline
% Rows
B\"uro & 12345 & 111 62 & 12:30 & 13:00  \\ 
aaaaa & 01573 & 111 34 22 &   & \\  
aaaaa & 0160 & 111 54 41 41 &   & \\  
aaaaa & 0173 & 111 25 22 & 09:00 & 09:30  \\  
aaaaa & 01516 & 111 12 30 & 12:30 & 13:00  \\  
aaaaaaa & 01520 & 111 37 89 & 15:00 & 15:10  \\  
\end{tabular}
    
\bigskip
    
\noindent\begin{tabular}{l@{\hskip 50pt}l@{ }l@{\hskip 35pt}r@{ - }l} 
%\begin{tabular}{ll@{ }lr@{ - }l} 
% Headline
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textbf{Betrieb viunhz \& jhgttaa}}  Betriebszeiten 08:00)07:00 - 16:30\\ \hline
% Spaltenbezeichnung
Ansprech & {Telefon} & & Pause von&bis \\ \hline
% Rows
bbbbbbb & 11111 & 222 22 22 & 09:00 & 09:20  \\ 
bbbbbbbb & 21212 & 222 55 22 & 12:00  & 12:30 \\  
bbbbbbbbbbb & 11111 & 111 33 02 & 15:00  & 15:30\\  
\end{tabular}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Confused, because the first one was not intended.

Comment: I think the first paragraph after the `\section{…}` never gets indented.

Comment: +1. You should mention the fact that the first paragraph after a sectioning header doesn't get indented up front in the very first paragraph of your answer. It's far more relevant than mentioning the default value of `\parindent`.

Comment: @Mico, well, thank you! Will edit right away!

Answer (score 2):

As already suggested by @leandriis in a comment, you may want to place both tables in a single `tabular` environment. This will guarantee that the columns are aligned across the tables.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\section*{Telefonlisten Ga xxx Ke e rs}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l r@{\space}l r@{--}l @{}}  
% header line
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Betrieb sssssss}} \\
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{Betriebszeiten (08:00)07:00--16:30}\\ 
\addlinespace\toprule
% Spaltenbezeichnung
Ansprech & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Telefon} & \llap{Pause von}&bis \\ 
\midrule
% Rows
B\"uro & 12345 & 111 62 & 12:30 & 13:00  \\ 
aaaaa & 01573 & 111 34 22 &   & \\  
aaaaa & 0160 & 111 54 41 41 &   & \\  
aaaaa & 0173 & 111 25 22 & 09:00 & 09:30  \\  
aaaaa & 01516 & 111 12 30 & 12:30 & 13:00  \\  
aaaaaaa & 01520 & 111 37 89 & 15:00 & 15:10  \\[1cm] 

% header line
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\textbf{Betrieb viunhz \& jhgttaa}} \\
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{Betriebszeiten (08:00)07:00--16:30}\\
\addlinespace\toprule
% Spaltenbezeichnung
Ansprech & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Telefon} & \llap{Pause von}&bis \\ 
\midrule
% Rows
bbbbbbb & 11111 & 222 22 22 & 09:00 & 09:20  \\ 
bbbbbbbb & 21212 & 222 55 22 & 12:00  & 12:30 \\  
bbbbbbbbbbb & 11111 & 111 33 02 & 15:00  & 15:30\\  
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice solution plus new knowhow (use of: @{}). What was motive for use of \llap{}? Isn't it counterproductive in table 1 because of the over lap in row 3 with "Pause" in columntitle?

Comment: @gizeh - `\llap` (short for "left-hand overlap", I suppose) is a text-mode command. It lets argument -- "Pause von" -- protrude into the preceding column header ("Telefon"). I can't see why this would be counterproductive.